# Finding a polar decomposition of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, svd, decomposition

I am trying to find the polar decomposition of a matrix.
I tried studying it from a video lecture : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjBEFOwHJoo
I tried implementing the way they have done, trusting their calculations of Eigen values and Eigen vectors as shown below and it gives correct value of `U` and `P` matrix.

```
A = np.array([[4,-14,1],[22,23,18],[15,10,20]])
A_T_multiply_A = np.array(A.T @ A)
print("A transpose into A")
print(A_T_multiply_A)


x = np.array([[-1,1,1],[0,-2,1],[1,1,1]])           # Eigen vectors
y = np.array([[25,0,0],[0,225,0],[0,0,2025]])      # Eigen values
z = np.linalg.inv(np.array([[-1,1,1],[0,-2,1],[1,1,1]]))    # Inverse Eigen vectors
A_transpose_A = x @ y @ z
print("A transpose A by multiplying Eigen vectors, Eigen values and Inv of Eigen vectors")
print(A_transpose_A)  
P  = x @ np.sqrt(y) @ z
print("Matrix P")
print(P)
U = A @ np.linalg.inv(P)
print("Matrix U")
print(U)
```

But when I try to implement the Eigen vectors and Eigen values using the API from numpy, the thing do not match:

```
import numpy as np

# Define the matrix
A = np.array([[4,-14,1],
              [22,23,18],
              [15,10,20]])
A_T_multiply_A = np.array(A.T @ A)

# Compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(A_T_multiply_A)

# Print the results
print("Eigenvalues:")
print(eigenvalues)

print("\nEigenvectors:")
print(eigenvectors)
```

Not sure why I am getting this difference?
It would be great if someone can explain me this or provide me some good link.

The values of Eigen values and Eigen vectors I got using numpy :

```
   Eigenvalues:
[2025.   25.  225.]

Eigenvectors:
[[-5.77350269e-01 -7.07106781e-01  4.08248290e-01]
 [-5.77350269e-01 -3.91901695e-16 -8.16496581e-01]
 [-5.77350269e-01  7.07106781e-01  4.08248290e-01]]
```

Also, providing the python code for calculating polar decomposition using a numpy API.

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.linalg import polar
    A = np.array([[4,-14,1],[22,23,18],[15,10,20]])
    U, P = polar(A)
    print("Matrix U=")
    print(U)
    print("Matrix P=")
    print(P)
```

The result is:

```
Matrix U=
[[ 6.00000000e-01 -8.00000000e-01  2.40023768e-16]
 [ 8.00000000e-01  6.00000000e-01  3.21346710e-16]
 [ 2.32191141e-16  6.61562711e-17  1.00000000e+00]]
Matrix P=
[[20. 10. 15.]
 [10. 25. 10.]
 [15. 10. 20.]]
```

Comment: Thank you @Onyambu for the response. Not sure how to do that because the API `np.linalg.eig` just gives out the value of EigenValues as `[2025, 25,  225]`. Not sure how to arange them in ascending order and then calculate eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes, I also think @Onyambu the eigenvectors are normalized but exactly what goes inside `np.linalg.eig`, I really do not know.  But the values shown in youtube lecture seems correct because final answer the answer calculated using `polar` API.

Comment: check the solution I provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `svd`:

```
import numpy as np

vecU, vals, vecV = np.linalg.svd(A)

P = vecV.T @ np.diag(vals) @ vecV
U = vecU @ vecV
P
array([[20., 10., 15.],
       [10., 25., 10.],
       [15., 10., 20.]])
U
array([[ 6.00000000e-01, -8.00000000e-01,  5.73090676e-16],
       [ 8.00000000e-01,  6.00000000e-01,  3.76857861e-16],
       [ 2.32191141e-16, -5.92653245e-17,  1.00000000e+00]])
```

Compare the results to what you have and you will notice they are the same

---

Solution using  Eigen decomposition:

```
Evals, Evec = np.linalg.eig(A.T @ A)
P = Evec @ np.diag(np.sqrt(Evals)) @ Evec.T
U = A @ Evec @ np.diag(1/np.sqrt(Evals)) @ Evec.T

P
array([[20., 10., 15.],
       [10., 25., 10.],
       [15., 10., 20.]])
U
array([[ 6.00000000e-01, -8.00000000e-01,  3.33066907e-16],
       [ 8.00000000e-01,  6.00000000e-01, -2.63677968e-16],
       [-9.71445147e-16, -1.66533454e-16,  1.00000000e+00]])
```

Comment: Actually, I have to explain my advisor what is going inside this `polar`, but  he will again ask me what going inside the `svd` using a basic code? @Onyambu

Comment: @m123416 updated using eigen decomposition as you want

Comment: Thank you great great help @Onyambu. I wasted hours on this today. This is a really really great solution.

Comment: @m123416 note that i you find yourself doing the `sqrt` of the eigen vals, then perhaps you might consider svd rather than eigen decomposition. The example above shows its easier to use svd. Check for the relationship between svd and eigen

Comment: Yes, I will use the `svd` solution  @Onyambu. Surely, it will give me better results.  I needed the eigen decomposition solution to understand exactly how the `svd` works.